# Apache throwing 500 error for a URL only in a few browsers

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, firefox, vhosts

Fellows, look what an odd situation...

My PHP application creates a compressed (.zip) file and saves it into a folder structure inside Apache's document root, alright?!

But it just happens that, in my computer, I manage to access the URL given only in Mozilla Firefox browser, Googles Chrome shows an error 500 (internal server error). Now, hold tight to your seats!! In my colleague's computer he could download the .zip file using Google Chrome but not with Mozilla Firefox.

It is the same URL for the same file, and the behavior of Apache changes from browser to browser, from machine to machine....

Guys, it's really strange to me. Anybody have faced something like that?

Cheers!

Comment: If you have access to the apache error log file, it will give you something to work with and share here.

Comment: Nothing, sadly, was printed in the log files, mate.

Comment: Add this to your php.ini file display_errors = on and check if the configuration of the apache log is correct, if necessary, raise the apache log level. Error 500 literally means "Something wrong and I don't know what"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happened that situation because of DNS misconfiguration. Running a `ping` command from several machines returned different IPs, then it was clear.